# How can I build a Docker container USING an OCI image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my company we use Docker 19.03.1 to work with containers on our desktops, and have our own container registry containing images copied from DockerHub etc.

I want to build an image `FROM` one such externally-sourced image, namely `envoyproxy/envoy`. But this is failing, apparently because it's an OCI-format image.

I can't even pull the image - it gives the same error as when I try to build my Dockerfile:

```
$ docker pull <my-company-registry>/.../envoyproxy/envoy:1.25.1
Error response from daemon: mediaType in manifest
should be 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json'
not 'application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json'
```

Note that I *was* able to run the envoy image in my company's managed Kubernetes cluster, although I guess that's using a different mechanism to my local Docker.

Is it possible for Docker to use this image for `pull`ing and `build`ing? If so, how?

Comment: Can you include the output of `docker buildx imagetools inspect <my-company-registry>/.../envoyproxy/envoy:1.25.1`. If the digest is not `sha256:d988076dfe0c92d6c7b8dac20e6b278c8de6c2f374f0f2b90976b7886f9a2852`, please include details of how you are copying this image.

Comment: I don't have buildx for some reason. I should mention that my company doesn't install a vanilla Docker Desktop which I guess is the reason I don't have buildx.

Comment: `regctl manifest get` (from regclient) or `crane manifest` (from google/go-containerregistry) would also work.

Comment: This is the output:
$ crane manifest containers-read..../container-external/docker.io/envoyproxy/envoy:v1.25.1
{
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.config.v1+json",
    "digest": "sha256:2ad34861f5b0fedb86cf65d1adc23f0f9d135b1272b64e7da8c8530ec9ff830a",
    "size": 3867
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip",
      "digest": "sha256:b549f31133a955f68f9fa0d93f18436c4a180e12184b999a8ecf14f7eaa83309",
      "...

Comment: Please use the "edit" button under your question to add additional details. And include details of how you are copying this image.

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to edit my previous comment. It's a company tool that copies the image from docker hub to our internal registry. I don't have visibility into how it works unfortunately. In any case, I was wondering whether the fact that this image is OCI format is a showstopper for docker build/pull